# Method of generating functions; Do we always get a symplectomorphism?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, symplectic-geometry

I am reading [this](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~acannas/Papers/lsg.pdf) very popular introduction on symplectic geometry by Cannas. The story goes as follows: Having manifolds $X_1, X_2$ , we want to construct symplectomorphisms between $M_1,M_2$ (where $M_i=T^*X_i$). Now to to that we use to things:

The first is that a closed $1-$form $w$ on the manifold $X$ defines $Χ_w=\{x,w_x\}$, a submanifold of $T^*X$. The fact that $dw=0$ forces $X_w$ to be Lagrangian. This means that for any function $f:X_1\times X_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , $X_{df}$ is a lagrangian submanifold.

On the other hands we have that a diffeomorphism $φ:X_1\rightarrow X_2$ is a symplectomoprhism if-f the graph of $φ$ in $(X_1\times X_2,\tilde{ω})$ is  lagrangian.

In the notes (page $29$ for example) it is said , or maybe I am misinterpreting something, that every $f:X_1\times X_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ gives rise to a symplectomorphism, by means of solving the corresponding hamiltonian equations. But I don't see a proof of that in the notes; So my question is : Is it true that the hamiltonian equations are always sovlable, i.e. the lagrangina submanifold $X_{df}$ is always the graph of a diffeomorphism ?

Comment: If you look at section 4.2 (p.31 in the PDF's numbering, p.23 in the book's numbering), it's stated that a *necessary* condition for this specific method to work is that the Hessian matrix of $f$ be nowhere singular. But we can certainly think of a function $f$ whose Hessian matrix is singular e.g. $f \equiv 0$ or $f = f(x)$. For these simple examples I just gave, we can rather easily visualize what is the set $Y^{\sigma}_{f} \subset M_1 \times M_2$ (book's notation) and it is clear that it is not the graph of a map $M_1 \to M_2$, let alone a symplectomorphism...